# Access Classes and API from jar which is also inside another jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have developed three separate Spring boot projects

- authentication
- authorization
- platform(Main Project)

My **main** project requires the jar of both **authentication** and **authorization** projects.

But, There are some classes present in **authorization** project which is required by the **authentication**, so one way was copy all the required stuff and pasted into the **authentication** project ***which is not an ideal practice or solution***. So what I did, I simply created the jar of authorization project and add the dependency in authentication's pom.xml.

Now because **authentication** is already in the classpath of **platform(Main Project)**, so I believe that **authorization** should also be present.

But in **platform(Main Project)** I am unable to access the classes of **authorization**.

**Authentication's pom.xml**

[image: AUTHENTICATION POM XML]

**Platform(Main Project)'s pom.xml**

In below snapshot it is clearly depicted that I have commented out the **authorization** dependency because it moves out to the **authentication**.
[image]

In below snapshot it is clearly depicted that I have commented out the **authorization** dependency because it moves out to the **authentication**.

I am not able to figured it out why this is happening, kindly help, it would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, spring boot JARs cannot be used as dependencies.